# Creating basic PHP script to add lines to a webpage

Tags: php, user-input, validation

I'm predominately a Java guy, which is why I need some assistance on what I assume is rather simple to do in PHP (and rather simple with Java too, although perhaps a bit... verbose).

Simply put, I want to construct a webpage which has a list of string items that users have added. At the bottom of the page would be a place in which a user could type "Hello World" in a box for instance and hit a submit button, adding it to the list of items. Adding to the top or the bottom of the list is irrelevant - I can probably tweak that later.

I'm the kind of guy who doesn't just like answers, but at the same time I have *no* idea where to even start searching. I've done no PHP development before. What sorts of constructs or functions should I be looking at? I own the physical box it'll be running on (it's literally right next to me now) so permissions aren't a restriction, and neither is getting anything else that might help the situation (although I can't see how it would be needed for such a simple script). What sorts of input validation should I be really wary of? This service will be restricted to people who have be given access to a particular section of an apache-based website, so they have to log in to even see this planned page, but I'd like to cover all possibilities.

Additionally, I would perhaps like output to look like

> "Hello World" added by user User1

"This is an additional line" added by User2

"Goodbye World" added by user User1

in the future. What should I be looking at to do this?

---

Update to answer questions:

When it comes to storage of the actual content, I'd be leaning towards a simple file holding each entry line by line, as Col. Shrapnel suggested. A think a database would be overkill, although I do have the wherewithal to implement it. If a user submits "Hello World!" then adding a line to a file that says

> "Hello World!" posted by User1

is sufficient.

With regards to authentication, this is already set up in apache's `httpd.conf` configuration file. Currently this allows access to a certain group of users through an `AuthGroupFile` entry. This is where the script will be hosted. To access this script, users will have already authenticated themselves with their credentials. The authentication currently works for that section of the site. Really, this is a *secondary* concern of mine. It is enough that lines are simply added with no record of who said what. This is just sugar on the PHP cake if it can be done easily with what I already have implemented.

Comment: Do you also have a MySQL/SQLite/PostgreSQL, or would you write in a text file? Not much difference, just...

Comment: What kind of storage you want to use?

Comment: Do you have this user database/login system already? If yes - what is it? If no - your question is quite ridiculous, as this auth system is 10 times more than this tiny snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, in PHP it's quite short.
Assuming Apache based authorization is used

```
<?
$file = "messages.txt";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
  $_POST['mess'] = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$_POST['mess']; 
  file_put_contents($file, $_POST['mess']." ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]);
  header("Location:".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
  exit;
}
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file)));
?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="mess">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Very concise, and I see exactly what's happening, but from what I can see this isn't applying any sanitation to the input?

Comment: @JBirch You did not stated any danger to protect from. But ok, make it `echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file)));` and `$_POST['mess'] = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$_POST['mess'];`

Comment: Is there a simple way to update the page when the submit button is pressed?

Comment: JBirch why do you think it is not?

Comment: The page simply goes white. I'm willing to bet this is an issue with my domain, though. At the moment it's just a shell pointing to an IP address. I should really get around to fixing that...

Comment: Well, it does do what I'd like. For some reason, the header function seems to return an error, but removing that line makes everything work. I'll look into `header()` and my environment a bit more in the coming days and see if I can get it working. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a few things to do:

- Pick a data store. MySQL is a popular choice when working with PHP. It doesn't sound like this'll be high-volume, so most any persistent store would work.
- When accepting input, you'll need to sanitize it for insertion into the DB (again, if using MySQL, [check the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)), and then you'll execute an INSERT statement to put it into the database.
- When displaying the page, you'll connect to the DB ([check the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)), query data from the data store, loop over it, and echo each line after sanitizing it of any potentially malicious data.

A short example might be something like:

```
<?
// Assuming a database named "my_database" with a table called "chat_lines", which has "username", "line", and "timestamp" fields.
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("my_database", $db);

// If data was posted to the script, scrub it and store it in the database.
if($_POST["username"] && $_POST["line"]) {
  mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO chat_lines (username, line, timestamp) VALUES (\"%s\", \"%s\", NOW())",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["line"])
  ));
}

// Fetch all lines from the database in reverse chronological order
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat_lines ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo sprintf("<div>%s said %s</div>", strip_tags($result["username"]), strip_tags($result["line"]));
}
?>

<form method="post">
  <div>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></div>
  <div>Line: <input type="text" name="line" /></div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

That example makes assumptions about users being allowed to enter whatever username they want (that is, it doesn't assume to implement the authentication system), the data store and the existence of the table and all that, but should get you started. The PHP documentation is pretty extensive, and can be very useful. In particular, read [Getting Started](http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php) and the [Language Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php).

Comment: I'm tempted to just hand out the answer right on the spot due to the flexibility of what you've given, although I think a database really is overkill here. I might combine elements of yours with Col Shrapnel.

However, I really would like the naming to be automatic. Not so much so people can't impersonate one another; that isn't an issue. More to just keep it as simple as necessary from a use standpoint.

Comment: @JBirch though the whole idea of DB sanitization is wrong. There is not a thing "input sanitization". that's totally a misconcept.